# Excel Deletes query table connection while running VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with an interesting problem that I have never experienced before and cannot seem to find any information about online. Here is the setup:

I am looping through a set of rows in a table - each row has a column for sheet name and a link from which I want to webscrape some data. I have written VBA code which loops through each row, creates a new sheet with the correct name, creates a querytable in that sheet, web scrapes the correct link and deletes the querytable.

Here is the code:

```
Sub WQ_Refresh(wsname As String, wqName As String, wqURL As String, strFC As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wq As QueryTable
Dim errno As Long
Dim loopcnt As Integer
Dim refreshTime As Double
Dim lastrow As Long

refreshTime = Timer

Application.StatusBar = "Now downloading " & wqName & " for " & strFC

If wsname = "" Then Exit Sub

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsname)

    If ws.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then

    Set wq = ws.QueryTables(1)

    wq.Delete

End If

lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 1 Then lastrow = lastrow + 1

Set wq = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & wqURL, Destination:=ws.Range("A" & lastrow))

errno = 1
loopcnt = 0

Do While Not (errno = 0 And loopcnt < 10)

    On Error Resume Next

    With wq

        .FieldNames = True
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete

    End With

    loopcnt = loopcnt + 1
    errno = Err.Number

    If loopcnt = 10 Then HashtagFail wqName

    On Error GoTo 0

Loop

If lastrow > 1 Then

   ws.Rows(lastrow - 1 & ":" & lastrow).Delete

End If

Set wq = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Downloaded " & wqName & " in " & Round(Timer - refreshTime, 0) & " seconds"
```

For some reason that I cannot understand, the `wq.Delete` function will correctly delete the created wq but it will also remove a connection in another sheet which is set up manually as part of the file.

To be clear - it does not DELETE the connection. It is still there but if you look at its properties, and go to the Used In tab, it shows as no longer used in any sheet.

I have no idea why this is happening - for me, the code should clearly delete only the connection in the sheet in the loop and not impact any other connections in the file.

This seems like a fundamental excel bug but I'd really like any input you have because I'm completely stuck.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: No repro. In empty workbook with 2 sheets: run this `Sub` using _Sheet1_ and URL of this question and stop after `Refresh`. Repeat with _Sheet2_ but this time let it run till the end. Result: only the connection in _Sheet2_ gets deleted, the other one is still connected to the query.

Comment: Have you tried executing your code step by step with F8 and detect the exact moment where your manual connection is deleted?

Comment: Have you tried setting and deleting the `QueryTable` using it's name instead of its index?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes I have. the manual connection is lost when wq.Delete gets executed

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers I believe so (i tried a lot of thing but I will check again just to be sure

Comment: Right before  `wq.Delete`, if you do `Debug.Print wq.Name`, does it return the right worksheet name where you want to delete the connection?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns It does

Comment: Same as @BrakNicku this problem can not be reproduce therefore it's very difficult to help beyond wild guesses and speculation. Could you share a workbook so we can see the problem increases the chances of providing a solution.

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers - using name and moving it out of the WITH clause seems to have solved the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment form @DeanDeVilliers The solution that worked was to reference the table by name. Here is the working code if anyone is curious

```
Sub WQ_Refresh(wsname As String, wqName As String, wqURL As String, strFC As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wq As QueryTable
Dim errno As Long
Dim loopcnt As Integer
Dim refreshTime As Double
Dim lastrow As Long

refreshTime = Timer

Application.StatusBar = "Now downloading " & wqName & " for " & strFC

If wsname = "" Then Exit Sub

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsname)

    If ws.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then ws.QueryTables("WQ_" & wqName).Delete





lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 1 Then lastrow = lastrow + 1

Set wq = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & wqURL, Destination:=ws.Range("A" & lastrow))

errno = 1
loopcnt = 0

Do While Not (errno = 0 And loopcnt < 10)

    On Error Resume Next

    With wq

        .FieldNames = True
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Name = "WQ_" & wqName
        ' .Delete

    End With

    loopcnt = loopcnt + 1
    errno = Err.Number

    If loopcnt = 10 Then HashtagFail wqName

    On Error GoTo 0

ws.QueryTables("WQ_" & wqName).Delete

Loop

If lastrow > 1 Then

   ws.Rows(lastrow - 1 & ":" & lastrow).Delete

End If

Set wq = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Downloaded " & wqName & " in " & Round(Timer - refreshTime, 0) & " seconds"

End Sub
```